# adding new object to vector, returns the same address every time

Tags: c++

I have the code:

My vector: `std::vector<spreadsheet> spreadsheets;`

```
//create a new spreadsheet if it doesn't already exist. Link the session to the spreadsheet.
bool server::createSpreadsheet(session* session, std::string name, std::string password)
{
    std::cout << "beginning" << std::endl;

    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < spreadsheets.size(); i++)
    {

      spreadsheet test = spreadsheets.at(i);
      std::cout << "spreadsheet name = " << &test << std::endl;
      if(spreadsheets.at(i).name == name) //spread sheet already exists
      {
          found = true;

      }
    }
    std::cout << "After For found = " << found << std::endl;

    if(!found) //create a spreadsheet
    {
      spreadsheet * spr = new spreadsheet(name, password);
      spr->linkSession(session);
      spreadsheets.push_back(*spr);
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "in else" << std::endl;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I was hoping this would create a new spreadsheet object each time `found` was `false` and place it in the vector. But based on the output I am getting it seems it putting the same object every time? Im at a lost as to what is going on here?

Output after running it several times:

```
beginning
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
spreadsheet name = 0x7fff568bce10
```

Comment: You're leaking memory, because what goes into the vector is only a copy of the object you dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You copy the spreadsheet to a local variable. And you output the address of the local variable.

If you want to output the address of teh spreadsheet in the vector itself you might do something like this:

std::cout << "spreadsheet name = " << &spreadsheets[i] << std::endl;

Comment: When I add an object to the vector, does it make a copy and add it?

Answer (score 1):

```
spreadsheet test = spreadsheets.at(i);
```

is a copy initialization. What that means is a new spreadsheet object `test` is created and whatever is in `spreadsheets.at(i)` is **copied by value to it**.

Then you are constantly taking the address of the new `test` object. **Not the address of the value in the vector.**

And the scope of `test` is within the for loop. So the compiler keeps allocating it in the same address on every iteration and shows you the same address.

If you want the address of what is `at(i)` in `spreadsheets` you will have to take its address directly

```
std::cout << "spreadsheet name = " << &spreadsheets.at(i) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Actually, when `=` appears in an initialization, it is not assignment. It is copy initialization(essentially just copy construction in this case). But +1 anyway, because it is otherwise a good answer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Noted. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems it putting the same object every time?

No. It's just that the temporary, local variable (`test`) is located at one particular place in memory, of course that address doesn't change. You have to inspect the contents of the object to be able to differentiate between them.

Also, the way you're using `vector` and `new` is at least horribly wrong. You're pushing back a **copy** of a `new`ly allocated spreadsheet object, superfluously calling a copy constructor, then you loose the pointer to the original object, leaking memory. When you retrieve the object from the vector, you're copying it again. Why don't you use a reference?

```
spreadsheet spr(name, password);
spr.linkSession(session);
spreadsheets.push_back(spr); // this copies too, but at least only once

// ...

/* optionally: const */ spreadsheet &test = spreadsheets.at(i);
```

Also, iterating through the vector using **iterators** is encouraged:

```
for (vector<spreadsheet>::iterator it = spreadsheets.begin(); it != spreadsheets.end(); it++) {
    // use `*it` to access the current element
}
```